# Undefined elements applying JavaScript "split" on Ant property

Tags: javascript, ant

Below are some lines from build.xml:

```
<property file="${basedir}\Model\src\ModelBundle.properties"/>
<property name="fullVersion" value="${CurrentReleaseView.SL_0_4}"/>

<script language="javascript">
    arr = project.getProperty('fullVersion').split('\\.');
    project.setProperty('version', arr[0]+"."+arr[1]+"."+arr[2]);
</script>

<condition property="build_no" value="${env.BUILD_NUMBER}" else="0">
    <isset property="env.BUILD_NUMBER"/>
</condition>
```

Later in the build.xml, I create a manifest.mf file:

```
<manifest file="${basedir}/src/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
    <attribute name="Manifest-Version" value="1.0" />
    <attribute name="Weblogic-Application-Version" value="${version}.${build_no}"/>
</manifest>
```

The value for `CurrentReleaseView.SL_0_4` in the property file is `v3.10.0.1p`.

In a development environment, the manifest file is created as expected:

```
Weblogic-Application-Version : v3.10.0.0
```

But in a production environment, the manifest.mf file is created with:

```
Weblogic-Application-Version: v3.10.0.1p.undefined.undefined.0.
```

We are using Ant version 1.8.2.

Can anyone please help me rectify the problem with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

In the following line...

```js
arr = project.getProperty('fullVersion').split('\\.');
```

...`split` is called like so...

```js
split('\\.')
```

The argument given to `split` (`'\\.'`) is a regular JavaScript string, not a regular expression. Since it is a regular string, the string actually represents two characters...

```
\.
```

So, `split('\\.')` means "split the string each time a backslash (`\`) precedes a period (`.`)."

In your code, it doesn't appear that `fullVersion` should contain backslashes. If that's the case, you probably want to split only on period characters and the following call to `split` should work...

```js
split('.')
```

Comment: I wonder if the original question is more about why the split function does not have the same behaviour according to the environment It happens that I have encountered this too as using `split(.)` works on my dev platform, but not in production. Same thing for `split('\.')`. Any ideas what can be the reason for this?